# drawBitmap not working with variables?

Tags: java, android, variables

I'm using the framework intorduced in the Beginning Android Games book,
It has a method called drawPixmap(), its definition is:

```
@Override
public void drawPixmap(Pixmap pixmap, int x, int y) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(((AndroidPixmap)pixmap).bitmap, x, y, null);
}
```

When I'm calling the function, let's say

```
g.drawPixmap(Assets.ball,200,200);
```

It works.
but when I use it like this

```
g.drawPixmap(Assets.ball,ball.getX(),ball.getY());
```

It doesn't.

I tried getting the X & Y to a local variable before, still no good.
both X and Y in the ball class are integers.

In the book, he shows a code which includes using variables. but I can't get this to work.

any ideas why it won't recognize my cute little variables?

#### Edit 1:

Now I noticed that in the constructor of that class, it does uses variables successfully.
only in the update() method it doesn't.

#### Edit 2:

I get a runtime error:

```
Fatal Exception Thread-10 java.lang.NullPointerException
```

`at com.carmel.android.accelpong.GameScreen.<init>`

But now I thing it's something with the ball class itself, as even when trying to set the X using the setX() methoed, I get the same error.. but it doesn't bring me any closer to solving this

Comment: I get a runtime error.
Fatal Exception Thread-10
java.lang.NullPointerExcepted

But now I thing it's something with the ball class itself, as even when trying to set the X using the setX() methoed, I get the same error.. but it doesn't bring me any closer to solving this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ball` variable is `null`. You are forgetting to initialize it, or somehow rewritting it. Include the code that goes from ball creation to invoking that function for a more detailed answer.

Comment: You're right. I just noticed that I forgot to initialized it.. que boludo....

now that I do, it works!

I guess that this is what I get for not sleeping at all..

Thanks all who helped!